# Preg_replace and regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like this:

```
$imgs = "uploads/images/adsense.png|uploads/images/tree-7835_960_720.jpg|uploads/images/way-427984_960_720.jpg|uploads/images/friendship-1081843_960_720.jpg|uploads/images/pinky-swear-329329_960_720.jpg"
```

I want only the part that refers to the first image:

```
uploads/imagens/adsense.png
```

How can I use regex to filter for the content before the first `|`?

```
$image = preg_replace(/(*)(\/*)/, $1 ,$imgs)
```

Comment: Just http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Either `explode` or `strpos` and `substr`. The latter is a bit faster.

Comment: What is your regex trying to do? Simple regex, `(.*?)\|`. This `(*)` makes no sense though. It is quantifying nothing.

Comment: I thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an input value like this:

```
$imgs = "uploads/images/adsense.png|uploads/images/tree-7835_960_720.jpg|uploads/images/way-427984_960_720.jpg|uploads/images/friendship-1081843_960_720.jpg|uploads/images/pinky-swear-329329_960_720.jpg"
```

You simply need to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it, using `|` as the delimiter:

```
$images = explode("|", $imgs);
```

The image you want is the first one:

```
$images[0];
```

While you *can* use regex, there is no particular reason to in this case, and it risks obfuscating what you're doing.

Comment: Could be made more-efficient with the explode limiter argument. `explode('|', $imgs, 1);`

Comment: Agreed! `explode("|", $imgs, 1)` would also get the job done, and terminate at the first found string. But there isn't any particular reason to complicate the code unless efficiency is actually at issue.

Comment: @NathanielFord Thank´s it works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Why use regex? You could just do:

```
substr($imgs, 0, strpos($imgs, '|'));
```

Comment: Thank´s @Eihwaz your code works well, I only chose the NathanielFord response because it is simpler

Comment: @Gisele We're here to help each other, the important thing is that you've found what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^([^|]*)/
```

This matches any number of characters from the beginning of the string to the first `|` character.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added <kbd>regex</kbd> tag.

You can use the `positive lookahead` like below, along with `^` anchor.

**Regex:** `^.*?(?=\|)`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE5yU9/1)**

Comment: I know lookaround assertions are a little inefficient. But it's also a valid solution. Care to explain down vote ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$upload = explode('|', $imgs);
echo $upload[0];
```

hope it helps :)